# Firebase auth: What details are in the currentUser object, and how to access them?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a project with React and Firebase. When my users register, the submit the following information:

```
email: ''
userId: ''
venueAddress: ''
venueName: ''
```

So far I can access the email and userId using `const user = auth().currentUser.email`, but I'd like to be able to extract the `venueName` property too - is this possible? Or can you only extract the email and password properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const user = auth().currentUser.email
```

Through this you are explicitly asking for email property of the currentUser object.

In order to access venueName property of the currentUser object use the following -

```
auth().currentUser.venueName
```

Also you can explore other properties as well of the object by using the following function -

```
auth().currentUser
```

Here is the firebase docs link you can look into for further info -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however auth().currentUser.venueName returned ```null```

Comment: Just console log auth().currentUser and let me know what comes there

Comment: Looks like you can grab currentUser.uid as well.

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Authentication user only contains the properties defined here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User. As you can see, these are only properties related to authentication itself.

A Firebase Authentication user does not include any application specific values, such as your `venueName`. If you want to track such values, you'll typically create a record for each user in your database that you associate with the user's UID.